# Run python code with sys.stdin using my own inputs

Tags: python, command-line

Hi I have a very naive question.

I have this piece of python code `test.py` that I am trying to test run.
May I know how do I run it using my own inputs?

I tried running it on my command line using
`python3 test.py ABCD` but the command line does not return anything..

I have also tried `python3 test.py ABCD.txt` where `ABCD.txt`contains the line ABCD but also to no avail...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
import sys
output = []
for ln in sys.stdin:
   for c in ln:
      if c in 'ABCD':
           output.append(c)
sys.stdout.write(''.join(output) + '\n')
```

Comment: use `python3 test.py < ABCD.txt`

Comment: Or `python3 test.py <<<'ABCD'`, if you only want one line of input. Or `echo ABCD | python3 test.py`, or... etc, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

`python3 test.py < ABCD.txt`  as suggested by keith works, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Running the code like `python code.py a b c d` will result in storing *a*, *b*, *c*, and *d* as input command line arguments. So to handle that you need to use `sys.argv` and edit the code as follows.

```
import sys
output = []
for ln in sys.argv:
   for c in ln:
      if c in 'ABCD':
           output.append(c)
sys.stdout.write(''.join(output) + '\n')
```

check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-python/) for more info.

However, all standard inputs to an application are handled using `<` command. Just like the standard output which is handled by `>`.
So to run the just add `<` like :`python3 test.py < ABCD` and it should be ok.

Comment: Modifying the code may not be an option. The question is how to provide standard input, not how to avoid reading standard input.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! ya unfortunately modifying the code is not an option, is there a way to run this code without changing it?